# Import glob, invalid syntax python

Tags: python, syntax, python-3.x, glob

Okay, I'm a noob when it comes to Python, I have to learn this for work.. And so far, I'm looking at some small programs to list directories.

I'm using Python 3.2.1.. In the Python Shell, I make a new window and I put:

```
import glob
print glob.glob("/*.txt")
```

But when I "run module", I save it, and it always tells me Invalid syntax, and it highlights the 2nd glob in the code.. Why?? Any idea on how to fix this? I don't really understand why I have an error..

Comment: In python 3, `print` is a function, so you need `print(glob.glob("/*.txt"))`, with the parentheses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`print` is a function in Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function). You can't use it as a statement like you would in the 2.x versions. Your code should work if written as:

```
import glob
print(glob.glob("/*.txt")) #Note the parens for print()
```

Comment: Ah.. that's so interesting, why the change in Python 3.. If you don't mind me asking.

Comment: @chakolatemilk: There were a couple of arguments for the change; the most prominent ones are outlined in [PEP 3105](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105#rationale). Largely it was concerns with consistency and modularity/extensibility.